# Исчезают стили если разрешение экрана меньше 992?

Tags: вёрстка

есть такой сайт [course-up.online](http://course-up.online)

В первые такое вижу, если разрешение экрана больше 992 все окей, если меньше то стили просто исчезают, хотя загрузка стилей есть. Кто может подсказать в чем дело?) Заранее спасибо

Comment: В [media-запросах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: Пожалуйста посмотрите пример сайта. Я стили описал, дело в том что они не применяются. Просто на разрешение 992 как будто файл стилей исчезает

Comment: Как я вам уже написал, дело в media-запросах. У вас там [множество стилей с ограничением на минимальную ширину](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlQsg.png) экрана.

Comment: Странная фигня, у меня отрендерились все стили и на всех разрешениях

Comment: @etterwin уже исправил)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Была проблема в валидации. Откуда то появились символы